# Debian 10: Cannot add my user to group

Tags: debian, permissions, users

I am trying to add my user to group `smbgroup`

```
sudo usermod -G smbgroup <username>
```

When I run this command no error is produced, however when I then run `groups` I do not see `smbgroup` listed in the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to add you should also use -a in addition to -G, or you'll replace. That's in addition to whatever other issue you might have.

Comment: @A.B Does this mean I've broken my system? Is there any way to restore the groups the user was a member of before?

Comment: If you did it only once, there's a backup in /etc/group-. If you didn't log off (as should be done as told in the answer), you can still see the current logged in user's groups (using id). Anyway you didn't break anything, except perhaps a few extra groups on this single user

Answer (score 0):

Did you log in again before running `groups`? If not, you won't see the new group show up yet.

You can check the configuration was changed in the meantime with `getent group smbgroup` or simply checking `/etc/groups`.

Answer (score 0):

Login to that group:

```
$ newgrp smbgroup
```